# Swipe Views with Title Strip (Material Design)

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a Material design for a title strip? (Not the regular tab bar)
I want to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzgY7.png).

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip)?